# Reusing host GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS in pods

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

Is there a way to inherit host environmental variables in the GKE pods?

I am specifically interested in GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS - container performs some internal project services and it would be great if I could reuse Compute Engine default Service Account as opposed to define a custom one.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you planning to inherit environment variables from?

By default, if you give your container cluster enough privileges (i.e. the  `--scopes` argument in `gcloud container clusters create`), containers will be able to use GCE machine’s IAM role and will be able to use the services listed in `--scopes`.

If you use `--scopes`, you don't need to specify any `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`, most Google Cloud client libraries will automatically use GCE instance’s identity to make requests.

Comment: Container engine. Does not seem to be picking them up in the pods themselves.